# OpenID2 for Google accounts is going away, rails and omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, google-openid

I can't seem to find anything about migrating away from openid for omniauth users? Is this as simple as changing the redirect url?

```
require "openid/store/filesystem"
require "omniauth-google-oauth2"
config.omniauth :google_apps,
store: OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'),
domain: "example.com",
identifier: "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `gem omniauth-google-oauth2`.

The ReadMe explains how to set it up.

`gem omniauth-google-apps` is now deprecated and no longer maintained.  It won't work after April 20, 2015 when google stops supporting openid.